# Split csv file by multiple columns values and keep header

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to split big tsv file into smaller parts depending on column value but I need to keep header in every file that was created by splitting. How can I do this?

I've tried some solutions but they can solve my problem only for particular files

```sh
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {h=$0};NR>1{print ((!a[$5]++ && !a[$9]++ && !a[$10]++)? h ORS $0 : $0) > "file_first-" $5 "_second-" $9 "_third-" $10 ".tsv"}' file.tsv
```

I expect to have header in each file, but for now it is only in files, where $5 $9 $10 are in such format : `1 1 1` `2 2 2`... But not the permutations.

Comment: Did you want `||` instead of `&&` when deciding whether to print the header?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask]. Tabs are hard to see so use commas or some other char instead throughout your problem - that solution you get for that char you can just tweak to work for tabs instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the following per-line logic:

```
calculate output_file
If !header_sent[output_file]
    Print Header to output_file
    set header_sent[output_file]
EndIf
print current line to output_file
```

Implementation in AWK below. Can be converted into one-liner by removing comments, and compacting variable names, etc.

```
NR == 1 { header=$0  }
NR > 1 {
    output_file = "file_first-" $5 "_second-" $9 "_third-" $10 ".tsv"
        # Send header, if not sent to this file yet.
    if (!header_sent[output_file] ) {
        print header > output_file
        header_sent[output_file] = 1
    }
        # Print the current line
    print $0 > output_file
}
```